# Hiding scrollbar in div

Tags: html, css, layout, scroll, overflow

Hello budding web enthusiasts. I am afraid that I am in quite a pickle and need a helping hand.
In a current web project, I ran into a sour wall. This here is the code. Take a gander. From the code, it does exactly what I want. **But here is the problem**.
There are scrollbars on the div. I dont want any scrollbars on my divs. I tried overflow-y:scroll; and got rid of the horizontal scrollbar but the vertical scrollbar is still there. I tried a lot and searched for it but to no avail. 
***How can I get rid of both the vertical and horizontal scrollbars in my divs with it still bieng able to scroll.***

> edit : I also need it to be cross browser functional. not only chrome.

HTML

```
<div id="content">
    <div id="left">
        <div class="richyPhoto"> </div>
    </div>

    <div id="right">
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
body {
    overflow:hidden;
}
#content, html, body {
    height: 100%;
    width:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
#left {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    background: red;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: scroll;
}
#right {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    background: blue;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: scroll;
}
```

Comment: Quick question... why would you want to get rid of the scroll bars?

Comment: I am making a website where two sides of a website (50% div left and 50% div right) scroll individually. So a scrollbar in the middle of the website would seem ugly and not in tune with the website.

Answer (score 2):

I would use this technique:

```
#parent{
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
overflow: hidden;
}

#child{
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
overflow: auto;
padding-right: 15px; /* Increase this value for cross-browser compatibility */
}
```

Here's a working Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5GCsJ/954/

Comment: i agree with u.  overflow:hidden remove scrollbar

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/2h4mw9du/ I cant seem to work my file. here is a fiddle. the red part need to scroll without the scrollbar.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to do it:
HTML

```
<div id="content">
    <div id="left">
        <div class="richyPhoto"> </div>
    </div>

    <div id="right">
       <div class="richyPhoto2"> </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
body {
    overflow:hidden;
}
#content, html, body {
    height: 100%;
    width:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
#left {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    background: red;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.richyPhoto {
    width: 100%;
    height: 99%;
    border: 1px solid red;
    overflow: auto;
    padding-right: 15px;
}
#right {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    background: blue;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.richyPhoto2 {
    width: 100%;
    height: 99%;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    overflow: auto;
    padding-right: 15px;
}
```

Working Fiddle link: [No scrollbars scroll](http://jsfiddle.net/amahajavon/01wnpfyn/)